# getting IOException "got minus one from a read call" while connecting to oracle 10g database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

getting IOException while connecting to oracle 10g database:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:190)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:363)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:839)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at com.myapp.struts.DBConnection.getDBConnection(DBConnection.java:21)
at com.myapp.struts.DBConnection.main(DBConnection.java:31)
```

Java Result: 1

my class code is following:-

```
package com.myapp.struts;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBConnection {
    Connection connection = null;
    public Connection getDBConnection()throws Exception{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    System.out.println("OUTPUUT     ********driver registered");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","system");
    System.out.println("OUTPUUT     ********connection established");
    return connection;

    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        ResultSet result = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM admin;";
        Connection con = null;
        con = db.getDBConnection();
        System.out.println("OUTPUUT     ********111111111");
        Statement st =con.createStatement();
        result = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery(query);
        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println("OUTPUUT     ********");
            System.out.println(result.getInt(1));
            System.out.println(result.getString(2));
            System.out.println(result.getString(3));
            System.out.println(result.getString(4));
        }
        con.close();


    } 
}
```

AND one more thing i am using netbeans ide and developing a struts project.
Struggling with this problem from last two days but yet to get the solution.

Please help????

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call during JDBC connection with oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363680/java-sql-sqlexception-io-exception-got-minus-one-from-a-read-call-during-jdbc)

Comment: Have you read [this](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/433151) ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: I have gone through more than these documents and their suggestions but still getting the problem.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Yeah, question is duplicate but answer is still not there?

Comment: Do you see this statement printed in the console - "OUTPUUT     ********driver registered"

Comment: @JtheRocker: Yes, it printed but not next....

Comment: OUTPUUT     ********connection established

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Facing problem to connect with Oracle 10g using JDBC, try below things:
1. turn off your machines's Wi-fi.
2. Stop Oracle Service.
3. Start Oracle Service.
Now try to connect with DataBase using JDBC. Problem will be resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing semicolon at the end of the query

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM admin";
```

Comment: removed but still same problem. by the way this thing will come next after connection establishment.

Comment: I got the problem solved just by replacing the connection url as: connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/XE","system","sy‌​stem"); thanks to everyone for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem solved just by replacing the connection url as: connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/XE","system","sy‌​stem"); thanks to everyone for your support.

Comment: Interesting, why is your localhost not pointing to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @JtheRocker:-I got the actual problem today. Problem is, when my machine is connected with some WI-FI and internet connection is up, this problem arises but it works fine if i disconnects the WI-Fi connection. I think oracle service, jdbc and WI-Fi have some conflict while running parallel.

Comment: @JtheRocker:- and one more thing after disabling wifi, restart of oracle service is necessary.

Comment: I haven't encountered a problem such a this - but you can try ping locahost to see which IP address it points when connected to Wi-Fi and when you are disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this url instead

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
```

or, `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe"`

You might also want to try this to track down your problem -

1. Remove the following while section temporarily

   ```
      while(result.next()){
           System.out.println("OUTPUUT     ********");
           System.out.println(result.getInt(1));
           System.out.println(result.getString(2));
           System.out.println(result.getString(3));
           System.out.println(result.getString(4));
       }
   ```
2. add this in place of the while loop - `result.first();`
3. add this too after that - `System.out.println(result.getString(1));`
4. Check if you have any exception now
5. If you don't get exception, I think, you are having issues with one or more or more of the result.getXXX() functions inside the while loop.

Is a kind of trial and error answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :- Thanks for the suggestion. but my problem is not that.

Comment: problem is here in below statement :

Comment: connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","system");
    System.out.println("OUTPUUT     ********connection established");

Comment: and infact problem is not with this statement also but with configration of oracle10g and i am not aware of that.

Comment: I though your connection was successful, when you said you could see the OUTPUUT ********connection established message.
Maybe if you post the version, database name, table structure and oracle configurations clearly, somebody might help you out here :)

Comment: No OUTPUUT ********connection established is not getting printed only driver is getting registered.

Comment: I got the problem solved just by replacing the connection url as: connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/XE","system","system"); thanks to everyone for your support.

Answer (score 0):

IF the database shutdown command is executed then it will not allow anymore new connections and this error will come.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem, I got over of it by replacing 8080 port to 1521
Thank you all
you all are doing great job for beginner like me