# Saving a Chunk of Data into DB from Java Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Java Batch Program which is triggered from a BPEL process used for inserting set of Record into DB.

Size of record might vary but at an average around 20,000 to 40,000.

My custom java batch picks up the data from an excel uploaded from a third party app into server location.

For performing the DML operation I have gone with Hibernate/Spring JDBC framework.

Refer to my spring configuration file as below::

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mybasepackage" />

<bean id="myProps"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:myDB.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${DB_DRIVER}" />
    <property name="url" value="${DB_URL}" />
    <property name="username" value="${DB_USER}" />
    <property name="password" value="${DB_PASSWORD}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="mypackage" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">7000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myBatchDao"
    class="mypackage.MyBatchDaoImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="myBatchService"
    class="mypackage.MyBatchServiceImpl">
    <property name="myBatchDao" ref="myBatchDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I am already using c3p0 for ConnectionPooling and also visited the following links:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660336/how-to-approach-a-got-minus-one-from-a-read-call-error-when-connecting-to-an-a)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363680/java-sql-sqlexception-io-exception-got-minus-one-from-a-read-call-during-jdbc)

But still I am getting following exception::

```
<org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper> <BEA-000000> <IO Error: Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 6370 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.>
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction;nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:564)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
```

Comment: I see no good reason to use JPA/Hibernate.  I'm guessing your batch job is reading a single worksheet and writing to a single table.  Simple.  Straight JDBC is sufficient.

Comment: No multiple tables are involved.I prefer to go with spring orm since framework will maintain the transaction and connection closing

Comment: I love Spring too, but I'd suggest sticking with JDBC template.  You don't need all that machinery.

Comment: Do you have any answer to this question??JdbcTemplate is not the solution of the problem

Comment: Can’t acquire connection.  I’d start stripping things out and making it simpler.  I can’t tell from what you’ve posted if the driver JAR is in the classpath, the driver and URL are right, etc. Do the simple thing and build from there.